# How to get back to insert mode in VIM when you accidentally hit C-x C-s

Tags: vim

Given this vim session:

```
% vim test-file.txt
iHello there!C-x C-s
```

How do I get back to insert/command mode again?
(C-x C-s means Control-x Control-s, not sure if it's normal vi terminology for keyboard shortcuts)

I know there's some way to get out of this and into insert/command mode again, but I just can't remember how and searching Google or superuser hasn't yielded me anything.

This happens since I mostly use emacs, but I use vim for remote hosts where I don't have emacs installed. Occasionally I do this and I figured I should learn how to get out instead of just restarting the terminal every time.

Comment: Aside: watch out for vim's decrement shortcut bound to C-x. I learned about this one the hard way. Full story on an old blog post: http://wemmick.blogspot.com/2005/09/geeky-friday-little-known-vim-feature.html

Comment: @DougHarris, this blog post is priceless! uhuhuhuhuuh thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

C-q. in a console C-s is scroll lock, resume is C-q

Answer (score 0):

If `C-q` does not work, this has worked for me:

- (1) close the console,
- (2) open a new terminal,
- (3) reopen the file in vi,
- (4) vi will warn you that the file is already open
- (5) enter 'R' for retry and save with `w-q`